# How can a Silicon Labs EFR32BG22 target (especially ThunderBoard) read data from its NCP Windows host?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My EFR32BG22 target sends I,Q,RSSI data to my windows host ok, but I need to know how host can send data back to the target.

For reading from target, the host uses the BGLIB and specifically in bg.c host awaits BG event gecko_evt_cte_receiver_connectionless_iq_report_id which contains I&Q and RSSI data from target.

But I can't find how the host uses BGLIB to send data back to target.

The Silicon Labs target project's name is:   ncp-locator-target-common
And the host project's name is:  ncp-locator-host-connectionless